# PySide error: module "qtquick" version 2.1 is not installed

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I´ve created a QtQuick application. I´d like to use Python (PySide) to call the application forms, so I started with the demo as shown here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Hello-World-in-PySide-and-QtQuick. I changed it to cal my qml file.

In the Qt qml file there are those imports:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
```

When I run the Python application, I got this error message:

```
Module "QtQuick" version 2.1 not installed.
```

However, when I run the application from Qt Creator it works nice.

What I´m doing wrong?

Tks in advance,

Mauro Assis

Answer (score 0):

QtQuick 2.x is only available in Qt5. PySide does not currently support Qt5.

The tutorial you linked to uses QtQuick 1.0, which is the version available in Qt4. If you want to use QtQuick 2.1, you will have to switch to [PyQt5](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5).